# Can't create foreign key with laravel database migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have a problem with my Laravel migrations :(

when i'm running php artisan migrate, it stops on a foreign key.

first migration

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('fichefrais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->char('idVisiteur', 4);
        $table->foreign('idVisiteur')->references('id')->on('visiteur');
        $table->char('mois',6);
        $table->primary(['idVisiteur', 'mois']);
        $table->integer('nbJustificatifs');
        $table->decimal('montantValide', 10, 2);
        $table->date('dateModif');
        $table->char('idEtat', 2);
        $table->foreign('idEtat')->references('id')->on('etat');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('fichefrais');
}
```

and the second

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('lignefraishorsforfait', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->char('idVisiteur', 4);
        $table->char('mois',6);
        $table->foreign('idVisiteur')->references('idVisiteur')->on('fichefrais');
        $table->foreign('mois')->references('mois')->on('fichefrais');
        $table->char('libelle', 100);
        $table->date('date');
        $table->decimal('montant', 10, 2);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('lignefraishorsforfait');
}
```

After running the command, I got this error :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> gsb_larave.#sql-176_b9 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table lignefraishors     forfait
> add constraint lignefraishorsforfait_mois_foreign foreign key
> (mois) references fichefrais (mois) on delete cascade on update
> cascade)
>
> [PDOException]
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> gsb_laravel.#sql-176_b9 (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
> incorrectly formed")

Comment: Issue maybe that you have a composite primary key on `fichefrais` and you are referencing it at two different FK on `lignefraishorsforfait`. Maybe try `$table->foreign(array('idVisiteur', 'mois')->references(array('idVisiteur', 'mois')->on('fichefrais');`

Comment: I thought it was something like that, so I tried your solution, and I still have the same error. When i'm trying to create the foreign key with phpmyadmin, the error talks about the column type, but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Does your **visiteur** table has an id as a primary key? If yes, does it have a **data type** has **char** and a **length** of **4**. The **idVisiteur** in ** lignefraishorsforfait** table has a data type of char which must be the same as the primary key in the **visiteur** table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the foreign key you are declaring **doesn't refer to a primary key**. If you want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, the column 'mois' in your 'fichefrais' table **must** be a column with a **unique constraint** on it

Answer (score 0):

First of all your foreign keys must refer to a primary key (which most of the time is 'id' column).

Also you should create the tables in this order:

1- 'etat' table(which i dont see bcs you did not posted the migration code,),

2- 'fichefrais' table,

3- 'lignefraishorsforfait' table.
Just change the dates on database/migrations like this (example):

```
    2020_09_11_150331_create_etat_table.php   
    2020_09_12_000000_create_fichefrais_table.php
    2020_09_13_000000_create_lignefraishorsforfait_table.php
```

You cannot create first the table which contains foreign key because will not have a key in which to refer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this migrations:

First migration (fichefrais):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('fichefrais', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('idVisiteur')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('idVisiteur')->references('id')->on('visiteur');
        $table->char('mois',6);
        $table->primary(['idVisiteur', 'mois']);
        $table->integer('nbJustificatifs');
        $table->decimal('montantValide', 10, 2);
        $table->date('dateModif');
        $table->integer('idEtat')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('idEtat')->references('id')->on('etat');
    });
}
```

Second migration (lignefraishorsforfait):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('lignefraishorsforfait', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->integer('mois')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('mois')->references('mois')->on('fichefrais');
        $table->integer('idVisiteur')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('idVisiteur')->references('idVisiteur')->on('fichefrais');
        $table->char('libelle', 100);
        $table->date('date');
        $table->decimal('montant', 10, 2);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using MySQL, so Are your tables defined in InnoDB engine? MyISAM doesn't accept foreign key...

Comment: This is better off as a comment then an answer.